# How to remove \n from data frame and move the data to new row

Tags: python, pandas

I have an pandas data frame which looks something like this

```
Index   column1   column2   column3
  0        3 \n9     2 \n89     8 \n56
  1        
  2        8         6          4
  3        4 \n9     12 \n12    32 \n5
  4                
  5         78       68           56
```

I want to get rid of `\n` and move the left over content to next like. Hence I want data frame something like this

```
Index   column1   column2   column3
  0        3        2          8
  1        9        89         56 
  2        8        6          4
  3        4        12         32
  4        9        12         5
  5        78       68         56
```

I have been able to remove `\n` using the replace function

`df1.replace(to_replace=[r"\\t|\\n|\\r", "\t|\n|\r"], value=["",""], regex=True)`

But i have not been able to move the integer value of 9,89,56 to next line. Is it possible

Sample data:

```
{'column1': {0: '3 \\n9', 1: '', 2: 8, 3: '4 \\n9', 4: '', 5: 78},
 'column2': {0: '2 \\n89', 1: '', 2: 6, 3: '12 \\n12', 4: '', 5: 68}, 
 'column3': {0: '8 \\n56', 1: '', 2: 4, 3: '32 \\n5', 4: '', 5: 56}}
```

Comment: Your actual data is vastly different from the one you originally provided. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
def expand(col):
    return (
        col.astype(str)
        .replace('', np.nan).dropna().str.split(r"\s\\n")
        .explode().reset_index(drop=True)
    )


df[["column1", "column2", "column3"]] = df[[
    "column1", "column2", "column3"]].apply(expand)
print(df)
```

This prints:

```
  column1 column2 column3
0       3       2       8
1       9      89      56
2       8       6       4
3       4      12      32
4       9      12       5
5      78      68      56
```

Comment: Hi @Shubham, thanks for your response. This really work well but not completely. Although 89 and 56 is moving to next line but interger '6' and '4' (which r just below 89 and 56) are getting replace by 'blanks'

Comment: Can you share a larger sample of your dataframe?

Comment: @hargurjeetsingh update your question with this dataframe.

Comment: as suggested...updated the data frame to the question

Comment: @jezrael yep, Thanks :)

Comment: The updated code prints the following, rows with index 2 and 5 are returning with blanks

   index column1 column2 column3
0      0       3       2       8
1      1       9      89      56
2      2                        
3      3       4      12      32
4      4       9      12       5
5      5

Comment: @hargurjeetsingh i have edited the answer check the updated answer now.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to define a function to flatten the columns:

```
from itertools import chain

def flatten(col):
    return list(chain.from_iterable([i for i in col.str.split(r" \\n") if i]))

df[["column2","column3"]] = df[["column2","column3"]].apply(flatten)

print (df)

   Index  column1 column2 column3
0      0        3       2       8
1      1        7      89      56
2      2        8       6       4
```

EDIT: With the new sample data, here is an updated method:

```
def flatten(col):
    return [i for i in chain.from_iterable(col.str.split(r" \n")) if i]

print (df.astype(str).apply(flatten))

  column1 column2 column3
0       3       2       8
1       9      89      56
2       8       6       4
3       4      12      32
4       9      12       5
5      78      68      56
```

Comment: Hi Henry, Sorry I am getting the below error

TypeError: ("'float' object is not iterable", 'occurred at index column2')

Comment: @hargurjeetsingh So it means your actual data is not like the sample you provided. Provide sample of real cases instead.

Comment: I trying the run the code on the sample data itself and not on the actual data. Getting error on the below line
df[["column2","column3"]] = df[["column2","column3"]].apply(flatten)

Comment: Try do a `df.to_dict()` and add it to your question.

Comment: Upon executing the code, I get this output

column1       [3, 9, , 8, 4, 9, , 78]
column2    [2, 89, , 6, 12, 12, , 68]
column3     [8, 56, , 4, 32, 5, , 56]

How i put this to a df and remove the nulls.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner using [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
df1[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']] = \
    df1[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].apply(
        lambda x: x.astype(str).str.extractall(r'([0-9]+)')\
             .reset_index(drop=True)[0])
```

Comment: @jcaiiz, Thanks for you response.
Although 89 and 56 is moving to the next line but '6' and '4' (which are jsut below 89 and 56) are getting replaced by NaN.

Comment: @hargurjeetsingh please provide more sample, and make sure are real test cases.

Comment: Updated dataframe in the question.Hope it might help

Comment: I edited the question son you can still have two methods of validations, glad to read that is working.